# Serverless Aurora Postgres privileges managment

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

Having Serverless Aurora Postgres service on AWS, and trying to create new schema in database and user associated with it via SQL query.

Connecting with admin credentials and issuing following SQL query gives success result without errors:

```
CREATE USER "qqqq";
GRANT "qqqq" TO CURRENT_USER;
ALTER USER "qqqq" PASSWORD 'qqqq';
CREATE SCHEMA "qqqq" AUTHORIZATION "qqqq";
CREATE TABLE "qqqq"."super_table"( "id" INT )  -- Table just for example
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE "qqqq"."super_table" TO "qqqq";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA "qqqq" TO "qqqq";
```

Unfortunately subsequent connection with `qqqq` credentials crashes with following error on Aurora serverless:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema qqqq at character 46
```

It seems that all necessary privileges for user/role `qqqq` had already been issued by `admin` user, but still not having access to schema.
Also, mentioned SQL query works well on local installation of Postgres 10, and fresh-created user `qqqq` has enough privileges to work with `qqqq` schema.

So question - that's wrong with SQL query above when it running on Aurora? Maybe is there known workaround for this? Thanks in advance.